# Android NDK GLES 2.0 Nothing Drawing

Tags: c++, android, opengl-es, drawing, android-ndk

I am trying to Draw with GLES 2.0 through the NDK, doing everything except creating the surface in C++, but nothing is drawing on the screen...And I can't figure out why.

I have tried/verified many different things and am still at a loss.

my last few guesses are these:

my textures are somehow now compatible with the screen:

I load textures like this:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->GetPixels());
```

but the default GLSurfaceView format is RGB_565

I tried this with no success:

```
mGLView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
```

and also this:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->GetPixels());
```

could texture format have anything to do with the problem? I have no reference because the Android SDK abstracts this away completely..

this is the shader I am using:

```
const char *vertexShader = "\
    uniform mat4 uMtxProjection; \
    uniform mat4 uMtxModelView; \
    attribute vec2 aPosition; \
    attribute vec2 aTexCoord; \
    varying vec2 vTexCoord; \
    void main() \
    { \
        gl_Position = uMtxProjection * (uMtxModelView * vec4(aPosition.x, aPosition.y, 0.0, 1.0)); \
        vTexCoord = aTexCoord; \
    }";

const char *fragmentShader = "\
    precision mediump float; \
    varying vec2 vTexCoord; \
    uniform sampler2D sTexture; \
    void main() \
    { \
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); \
    }";
```

After further testing, and removing the texture(filling triangle with only red) I can see a distorted red box flash exactly 3 times each time the app is run, then the screen goes blank =/

and the ortho matrix:

```
Mat4 Ortho2D(float left, float right, float bottom, T top, float zNear, float zFar)
{
    float dx = right - left;
    float dy = top - bottom;
    float dz = zFar - zNear;

    // avoid division by zero
    float tx = (dx != 0) ? -(right + left) / dx : 0;
    float ty = (dy != 0) ? -(top + bottom) / dy : 0;
    float tz = (dz != 0) ? -(zFar + zNear) / dz : 0;

    return Mat4(2.0f / dx, 0,           0,          tx,
                0,          2.0f / dy, 0,           ty,
                0,          0,          -2.0f / dz, tz,
                0,          0,          0,          1);
}
```

Comment: Start with the basics.  Is your glClearColor what you expect it to be?  Are your shaders loading without any errors?

Comment: yes. The screen is cleared properly to the specified color, and shader errors(or lack thereof) are indeed printed to the console. I have also verified that my ortho matrix function produces an identical matrix to glOrtho().

Comment: actually, I have taken the texture out of the equation now, and simply fill the triangle with red, and now, I get a few quick distorted flashes of red, but only for the first half second the app runs =/

Comment: Can you post the code where you calculate your Modelview and Projection matrices?  And your draw loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I'm not sure what was going on exactly, but something I changed fixed the problem =/
I tried going back over the code to re-break it, but couldn't..

but for reference, I can't guarantee what was broken, but I can say for sure, that the problem was neither the texture, nor the shader. Even though the default surface view is set to RGB_565, using the following line creates a texture just fine in NDK, **with** working alpha.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->GetPixels());
```

The projection matrix that I was using was also fine, because I copied it directly from the openGL specs.

I noticed while working that the call glEnable(TEXTURE_2D) was causing an error (invalid enum) because it pertains to the fixed function pipeline of opengl, and I was using GLES2.0... and I was copying some of my old code from a fixed function implementation GLES1. So all I can think of was that I was causing gl to crash somehow by with the old code =/